# How to protect my PHP website from the .htaccess URL redirect malware script attack?

Tags: php, malware

**How this .htaccess file was injected into the website with malware code?**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*(msn|search|live|altavista|excite|ask|aol|google|mail|bing|yahoo).*$ [NC]
</IfModule>
```

**How can I prevent my website from same attack?**

This link was useful till some extent
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16361/how-to-prevent-my-website-from-getting-malware-injection-attacks

but my team expects me **to protect the website using coding. Is this is possible?**

I also found that few other websites had a similar attack but they use a specific kind of code to prevent their website. I cannot use those script because that's not suitable for me exactly.

The website is a core php website. If moderators found this question to be a not real question or an exact duplicate then before closing or hitting minus, please provide help with a link. I trust this website.

Comment: That code doesn't look malicious. It doesn't even do anything.

Comment: i think the point is, how it got there in the first place? malicious or not that comes after that.

Comment: Maybe it came as part of a framework?

Comment: This code has redirected to a website. I don have the URL now. The security.stackexchange.com says this kind of script translate the code into an URL and inject it in run time. So while we try to access our website it would be redirected to a translated URL and takes us to a different website.

Comment: You can't "protect the website using coding". It is literally impossible. That is why the servers are being configured, monitored and audited. Whoever on your team thinks otherwise is lazy or is trying to unload the responsibility.
You can theoretically overload all PHP fopen functions with some extensions that allow overloading of core PHP functions, to check what is being opened on the filesystem but this is a plain stupid workaround. 
What has to be done, is just disable .htaccess in Apache or at least limit its usage to certain categories that are not writable by effective Apache user.

Comment: I have the impression you don't really know how that supposed attack actually works, yet you want to protect yourself against it. That is impossible. Find out what the actual problem is (if there is any...) and _then_ you can think of a solution.

Comment: @WaleedKhan That code is part of a multi-part exploit to redirect all traffic originating from a search engine to some 3rd-party url.  The malicious part of the code was apparently either not posted, buried somewhere else in the codebase, or possibly not injected correctly by the hacker's script.

Comment: Lubnah - Comment is progressive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using timthumb.php or a similar upload / linking script?  Older versions are frought with XSS vulnerabilities.  It's a very common vulnerability on Wordpress installations, especially those which use themes that come bundled with their own timthumb.php / thumb.php.

If that's the issue, lock that script down!  If it's a custom script, take a look at the latest [timthumb.php source code](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) & try to use some of their techniques.

Also, make sure your file permissions are locked down for the apache / web users & groups.  E.G., do NOT allow .htaccess to be writable by apache user/group!

Answer (score 0):

> How this .htaccess code was injected into the .htaccess file?

If it has been injected then either someone has got root on your machine (not going to conjecture why/how) or your permissions model is wrong.

If someone has root, then you are totally PWNed - brush up your CV and go looking for another job - you don't need to bother reading the rest of this post.

But it's much more likely that the permissions are wrong (but even this, on its own is not sufficient for the files to be modified - you have a vulnerability elsewhere).

You should be able to identify the primary vulnerability. If you don't know how to do this then get some help. In addition to fixing this, you need to fix the permissions on your site. Only specifically designated locations should be writeable by the webserver uid - and if these are inside the document root then you should take appropriate measures to protect your system from code injection (disable PHP access, preferably all webserver access, although this is still a lot less secure than keeping it outside the document root altogether).